# How to get rid of bubbles?

Tags: solutions

Certain solutions, such as aqueous SDS or soapy waters, after being shaken evolve a lot of bubbles. These bubbles disappear over time, but it can take minutes or sometimes hours (eg. for 20% SDS).

Is there anything that can be done to accelerate the popping of these bubbles? For instance, would heating the solution affect the rate of bubble collapse?

Note: I am interested in methods that do not alter the chemical properties of the solution. For instance, I know that adding certain substances can affect bubbles, but if I added those then the solution would be something different from what I wanted in the first place. It is assumed that procedures such as heating are not sufficiently energetic to cause a noteworthy reaction.

Comment: Centrifuge the sample?

Answer (score 3):

Without addition of chemicals? Try out ultrasound (the same physical principle opticians use to clean your pair of glasses).  If you whish, this may be handled even [contact less](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArQ5X-9tXGk) ([some background](http://www.pusonics.es/productos/ultrasonic-defoaming_2632656_1.html) and [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1002/1521-4125(200106)24:6%3C659::AID-CEAT659%3E3.0.CO;2-1/abstract)), to mention examples.